# What factors influence whether a lens and camera combination front or back focus?

Tags: autofocus, focus, focus-adjust, back-focus, front-focus

I know that sometimes a lens/body combo needs to be micro-adjusted to attain ideal focusing behavior, and that this is usually because of sample variation, but which parts of the lens and/or body are actually the primary causes of front/back focus?

Comment: "must"? No. Definitely no "must". In some cases needs to be is the better answer. Also maybe see here, the answer is "both": http://www.canonrumors.com/tech-articles/this-lens-is-soft-and-other-myths/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be any number of different things. It all comes down to the tolerences that consumer cameras are built to.

Typical suspects would include:

- Lens Element locations
- Flange-to-film distance
- Sensor location
- Focus sensor

It is all about the location of the focal plane as outlined here: [What is back-focusing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/900/what-is-back-focusing)