# Can I fine tune the autofocus on my Canon 60D to be more accurate?

Tags: autofocus, canon-60d, focus-adjust

I noticed that some of my lenses auto-focus more accurately then others. (Assume perfect light conditions and fast shutter speed) Zooming-in on say the center focus point (if only the center focus point has been used) sometimes reveals that the lens overshoot or undershoot the focus just ever so slightly.  I also almost always get a better and sharper image when focusing manually (and breathing correctly). I mean the autofocus is not bad (seems best on my prime 50mm lens, less perfect on my 70-200mm telephoto) but not perfect.

I might now be thinking this up as I write along but If I remember correctly I've read somewhere that the Canon 50D body has some kind of an feature that can fine tune the AF for differently for different lenses.

In the end I decided to go with the Canon 60D body. My question is: Is it possible to somehow calibrate the auto-focus with my body to perform more accurately?

Comment: For cameras which _do_ have the adjustment feature, see this question: [What is the best way to micro-adjust a lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-the-best-way-to-micro-adjust-a-lens)

Comment: @mattdm - does the solution in this question also apply to the 60D or is this specific to the 7D. It says "If the focus changes, dial in microadjustment in the correct direction and repeat."  How?

Comment: As @rfusca notes in his answer below, unfortunately the Canon 60D does not have the micro-adjust feature. This is one of the things they dropped from the 50D, apparently as part of an overall strategy to position the line as an upgraded Rebel rather than a cheap semi-pro alternative to the 7D.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You adjust focus on the camera - not the lens.  The Canon 60D does not have a micro focus adjustment needed to do this.

You may try sending in your camera and lenses in for adjustment together, but it is not something you can adjust yourself on that body.

If your 70-200 is significantly slower in max aperture than your 50mm, then it likely doesn't autofocus as well because of the slower aperture.  More light = better autofocus.

Comment: Canon does not make a 70-200 f/4-5.6. All of the 70-200's include the "L" designation, which by most accounts can also be termed "professional", not consumer.

Comment: Oops, you are correct, was thinking of the 50-200 for Canon. Corrected.

Comment: Hm. That's probably the case. the 50mm is f1.4 and the telephoto is f/4.

Comment: f/4 really isn't *too bad* - its no 1.4, but its not like its f/6.3 .  You may try using a focus test chart in bright light just to verify.