# How do repair shops fix focus shifts on bodies lacking focus microadjustment feature?

Tags: autofocus, color-management, back-focus, focus-adjust, front-focus

For camera bodies without autofocus microadjustment capability, how do repair shops calibrate a specific body and a lens combination suffering from the focus shifts (back and/or front focusing)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These cameras *have* microadjustment capability, just not in a user-accessible way.

The exact method varies by model. Some have a software feature in an advanced (and secret) "debug" menu — the [Pentax K10D, for example, had this](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/post/22013971). Others have physical adjustment screws or similar (like earlier [Canon Rebel models](http://www.astrosurf.com/buil/autofocus/adjust.htm)). Or, repair centers may simply use [shims](http://ghonis2.ho8.com/rebelmod450d6a.html).

To find the exact answer for a given model, you could either dissect the camera and look, or find the repair manual.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was suspecting that those bodies do have it, albeit without exposing it to the end user. I own a Canon 60D and I keep wondering if there is a way to enable the microadjustment via software... Magic Lantern, perhaps?

Comment: @insignum For that specific model, check out [Can I fine tune the autofocus on my Canon 60D to be more accurate?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14957/can-i-fine-tune-the-autofocus-on-my-canon-60d-to-be-more-accurate) — although so far the best answer is "send it in".

Comment: mattdm: Could you please elaborate about dissecting the camera. What exactly am I looking for inside? Also, are there freely available repair manuals for Canon models?