# What are these bands called?

Tags: distortion, banding

I wanted to know what this sort of distortion / artefact is called?
[image: incomplete bridge over water with banding effect]

Comment: This is named moiré

Comment: @RomeoNinov Your comment is a completely correct answer. Can I ask why you didn't simply enter it as an "official" answer. It's not as if you are new here, or anything.

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks! Can you help me understand why this image would have moiré?

Comment: @RiddhimanDasgupta, did you read the Q/A (following the link)?

Comment: It could be a photo of a computer display, rather than directly a photo of a bridge.

Comment: @Tetsujin, IMHO you are correct. For me also it is visible this is photo of image on display :)

Comment: @GrantRobertson [https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: [A beneficial use of the moire produced](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/9984/15871) when digitally imaging a screen.